# Prove f is a constant

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is defined on a unit disc. $f(z)$ and $f(\bar{z})$ are analytic functions of z, then $f$ must be a constant.

I have tried using Cauchy_Riemann equations, but haven't able prove the problem. I would appreciate any hint, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$f(z) = f(x+iy) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$.  Since $f(z)$ is analytic then $u_x = v_y$ and $u_y = -v_x$.

$f(\overline z) = f(x-iy) = f(x+i[-y]) = u(x,-y) + iv(x,-y)$.  Since $f(\overline z)$ is analytic, then $u_x = -v_y$ (we get $-v_y$ from the chain rule) and $-u_y = -v_x$ (we get $-u_y$ from the chain rule) which means $u_y = v_x$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: thanks a lot! I was confusing myself when doing the chain rule